# Sprite image not displaying in pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

My sprite image is not displaying in the pygame window. It's probably something really simple, but I don't understand why it isn't showing. I'm fairly new to programming, so it's probably why I don't understand this. Is it something I've done wrong in the class itself? Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

windowwidth = 600
windowheight = 600
WALLWIDTH = 30
WALLHEIGHT = 30
PLAYERWIDTH = 20
PLAYERHEIGHT = 20

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
LIMEGREEN = (50, 205, 50)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('Green circle png.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x = x
        self.change_y = y

    def update_pos(self, x, y):
        old_x_pos = self.rect.x
        new_x_pos = old_x_pos + self.change_x
        self.rect.x = new_x_pos

        old_y_pos = self.rect.y
        new_y_pos = old_y_pos + self.change_y
        self.rect.x = new_y_pos

def main():

    pygame.init()

    thescreen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Maze Game')
    thescreen.fill((BLACK))

    mainclock = pygame.time.Clock()

    running = True
    while running == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w):
                    Player.changespeed = (-3, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s):
                    Player.changespeed = (3, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, -3)
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 3)
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)


        mainclock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: (i) You never actually create a `Player` object. (ii) Even if you did, you have no code for drawing the player!

Comment: Right thanks! :) wondering where I went wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the player on the screen. Call some code to draw it, (this is easiest to do in a render updates group but you could simply blit it as well). You probably also want to call the update function, but I won't include that in my example. Here is what you can do:

```
players = pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates()
players.add(Player(200,200))
def mainloop():
    while running == True:
        pygame.display.update(players.draw(thescreen))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w):
                    Player.changespeed = (-3, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s):
                    Player.changespeed = (3, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, -3)
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 3)
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d):
                    Player.changespeed = (0, 0)
```